# Barcode Scanner that communicates via RESTful API

Tags: wireless, scanner, web-server, web-development

I am project managing the development of a web app that needs to interface with a wireless bar code scanner.

Ideally I do not want to have to have a local host computer on site for the scanners to connect to / use as a gateway. I don't know if they exist but I was hoping to find a scanner that would connect to the internet via wifi and send the number it scanned to a specific API/WebService or that my webapp could poll the device for scanned codes.

**To put it more concisely can you recommend a wireless barcode scanner that can directly interface with a web based application?**

### Requirements:

Connects to wifi directly with no gateway device needed.

Interfaces with a webapp via a exposed web service or API.

Expense is not an issue, device must be supported as it will form part of a critical government system.

Sorry if I have been vague, happy to answer any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: As barcode is just another form of encoding text usually barcode scanners function like a keyboard and the text is sent to the currently focused window. As such I doubt you are going to find what you need. All those nice barcode scanners like delivery people use usually have some kind of computer (think 10-year old mobile) bult in, so maybe get something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Barcode POS terminal](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/barcode-pos-terminal)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I am considering similar. Wondering if an ESP32 using BT to talk to a BT scanner may bridge the gap between product and requirement

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Zebra MT2000](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/scanners/rugged-scanners.html)?

(**emphasis** added by me)

> Combines advanced 1D/2D barcode, DPM and image capture with the ability to key in and view data - **plus 802.11a/b/g** and Bluetooth connectivity options.