# Barcode POS terminal

Tags: web-development, barcode-scanner

I need a barcode terminal device for access controls workflow, this device needs to be connected to a web-application. In other words I need what can be a browser and a barcode scanner together.
Price limit 500$

Answer (score 2):

The **[Motorola MC40N0](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Motorola-Symbol-MC40N0-Touch-Computer-Barcode-Scanner-/162156587458?hash=item25c14929c2:g:9a4AAOSwaB5XoNzm)** provides an android-based barcode scanner system which can access web applications via the android browser wirelessly. It includes a barcode scanner, laser scanner, camera, and magnetic strip reader. Software to utilize the scanning methods should come stock on the included Android ROM, otherwise you'll have to buy a license from Motorola, which will ruin your budget. An older model, it can be found on the used market for cheap.

I owned two of these devices, having found them in a dumpster. After charging them up, both worked fine, though one had a battery that wouldn't charge. Their OMAP 800mhz dual core ARM CPUs were somewhat slow, but sufficient for the job, and the devices were incredibly efficient and long-lasting.

Comment: Is the barcode scanner in keyboard emulation?

Comment: Seems to be over my budget, is not it?

Comment: Yes it has a soft keyboard; mine were running android 4.2. The link I provided showed $299. Other deals on used models are probably available slat similar prices if you look for them.